# What is the canonical way to integrating an array over another

Tags: matlab, octave, octave-gui

consider the two arrays:

```
x = [0 .05 .1 .3 .32 .4 .55 .7 1 1.3 1.4 1.45 1.6 1.8 1.9 2 2.2 2.3 2.6 2.8 2.91 3];
y = x.^2;
```

I want to integrate `y` over `x`. So far, I have figured out that I can use the `trapz()` function in a for loop:

```
y1 = zeros(length(x));

for ii = 1:length(x)
    y1(ii) = trapz(x(1:ii), y(1:ii));
end

plot(x, y1, x, y);
```

However, I wondered if there is a canonical way to do this without using a for loop.

**P.S.1.** I suppose MATLAB/Octave are vectorized functions, and there should be predefined functions to take care of this sort of stuff.

**P.S.2.** I do not own a MATLAB license now, but the answer must be compatible with both MATLAB and Octave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [`cumtrapz( )` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html?searchHighlight=cumtrapz&s_tid=srchtitle):

```
y1 = zeros(length(x), 1);

y1 = cumtrapz(x, y)
plot(x, y1, x, y);
```

Comment: It is just for the uniformly spaced data though.

Comment: No need to use `y1 = zeros(length(x), 1);` since you throw this away in the next line. See ["Ineffective Preallocation"](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2016/08/01/ineffective-preallocation/)

Comment: @Foad `cumtrapz` works for non-uniform spacing too. Example: `x = linspace(0,3,1e4).^2; cumtrapz(x, exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` and `diff`:

```
y1 = [0 cumsum((y(1:end-1) + diff(y)/2) .* diff(x))];
```